# Why does the uv texture looks blurred?

Tags: texturing

[image]

[image] I have UV Mapped to my model. Why does the texture look blurred?. May I know where I'm going wrong? And how can I get a good result with UV Mapping. There are 2 images attached: one is the model showing the blurred image and other is the image attached on my model.

[image]

Comment: @Timaroberts sorry im weak in node so i do not go in nodes section. Its normal texture uv mapping a blend file attach.

Comment: This has nothing to do with a node setup. You used "Project from View" instead proper UV unwrap your mesh. These are very basic things you clearly need to learn if you want to succeed in 3d modeling.

Comment: can u help me how can i and what wrong im doing with my mesh unwrap.

Comment: There are literally thousands of videos and websites out there which do that way better than we can here on BlenderSE with our limited space and time. As I said, it's a very basic task, just look for "UV mapping" and "UV unwrapping". The next step would be "Texture Painting" to reduce the seams. Oh, and one hint. I do have as much desire to write tutorials for "u" as "u" have the desire to use proper language.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your texture is not "blurred", it's "stretched". This happens when the quads in the UV map are not regoular. Start with selecting an edge loop of your mesh, Ctrl E "Mark seams" then U Unwrap. In the UV/Image editor you can check how much regoular are the quads. As UV unwrapping is a sort of artwork, you will have to practice and search for tutorials for have a better understanding of all techniques involved.